# What is ArrayBuffer copyToArray's Implementation?

Tags: arrays, list, scala

When I navigate `ArrayBuffer[Byte]().toArray` implementation in my IDE, it takes me to,

```
def toArray[B >: A : ClassTag]: Array[B] = {
  if (isTraversableAgain) {
    val result = new Array[B](size)
    copyToArray(result, 0)
    result
  }
  else toBuffer.toArray
}
```

`copyToArray` implementation takes me to,

```
  def copyToArray[B >: A](xs: Array[B], start: Int): Unit =
    copyToArray(xs, start, xs.length - start)
```

the `copyToArray` with three args terminates in,

```
  def copyToArray[B >: A](xs: Array[B], start: Int, len: Int): Unit
```

Cannot locate what implementation of `copyToArray` is used on runtime. What's the implementation that's used? Is there a way to discover the implementations IDE doesn't trivially navigate to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toArray` and `copyToArray[B >: A](Array[B], Int)` definitions are in some superclass/supertrait of `ArrayBuffer`. Because you are already looking at a supertype, when you ask your IDE to take you to the definition of `copyToArray[B >: A](Array[B], Int, Int)`, it only looks further "up" the inheritance tree, and apparently it only finds an abstract declaration for it. You need to look "down" to find the actual implementation overrides this declaration. Your IDE should have some kind of "find implementations" function. In this case, the `ArrayBuffer` class itself has [the final definition](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1a250cb4c14f7999fb610dd6f8d163ab65aa5aa7/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.scala#L218-L224).

Comment: I see. Could you also please point me to the `copyToArray` implementation used in Scala 2.11.12? Doesn't seem to be in `ArrayBuffer` class https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.scala

Comment: Also, Find Implementations is not working in my case - When I press Opt+Cmd+B in my IntelliJ IDE it says `No Implementation Found`. Am I missing something here? I use Find Implementations in application layer code and the functionality seems to be working fine on that.

Comment: @haltTm Either IntelliJ is being defeated by the wonkiness of the collection library (unfortunate but not unexpected) or (at least I think this option exists) you've set IntelliJ to "ignore implementations in libraries" or something. Anyway, I don't have an installation of it right now, so I just opened up a REPL and instigated a stack trace (`try { (1 to 10).to[ArrayBuffer].copyToArray(null, 0, 0) } catch { case e => e.printStackTrace() }`). https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2e2f65a201b0b06e01a39fec4ae232c5b94efcca/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ResizableArray.scala#L75-L78

Comment: thanks, generating a stacktrace by erroring out the code is definitely a neat trick. I will continue to investigate why my IDE is misbehaving and post an update